# Логика получения баланса пользователя

Tags: php, mysql

в базе есть таблицы `clients, transactions и costs`. Если вы уже заметили то в таблице `clients` хранится информация о клиентах в том числе и о балансе, в таблице `transactions` хранится информация о денежных поступлениях для каждого клиента. А в таблице `costs` как правило записывается расходы каждого клиента. Каждая таблица связана между собой с `client_id` что содержит уникальный ключ для каждого клиента. Нужен совет насчет логики получения баланса пользователя каждый раз при входе в систему например. Как бы Вы получали баланс пользователя при таком раскладе базы данных? или нужно добавить ещё какую то промежуточную таблицу ? Поделитесь мыслями, друзья. Что от чего и как нужно отнять чтоб получать баланса клиента. Благодарю за ранее

Comment: у вас есть баланс уже в таблице clients, какую логику вы пытаетесь придумать?

Comment: "_Если вы уже заметили то в таблице clients хранится информация о клиентах в том числе и о балансе_" Нет, мы не заметили, структуру таблиц вы не привели. Если БД полностью нормализована, то в таблице clients баланса быть не может. Если же она денормализована, видимо для целей быстродействия, то баланс в clients все таки есть, как вы написали. Там он конечно же ведется автоматически с помощью триггеров на двух других таблицах. И тогда ответ на ваш вопрос "взять баланс из clients и показать".